# Portable car audio system

Tags: audio, lithium-ion, radio, automotive, 18650

Before getting hurt we want to ask trained people, just to make sure our assumptions are true.
We have a pioneer MVH-S320BT car radio, 1 subwoofer, 2 tweeters, and 2 woofers, so our idea is to link the speakers to the car radio and power up with a lithium-ion battery to make the whole standalone and portable. This gets to the crux of the issue, I've thought to make a 12v 20 amps lithium-ion battery pack (currently we have 18 pcs of 18650 cells, so probably we will buy others) in order to power up the car radio since its max consumption is about 200 w but I don't know if this is enough or if we have to consider other parameters like speakers impedance or similar. Another problem will be maybe the battery life (i think).
I must say that this project is just for fun and for academic purposes but obviously, we want to be sure of what we do to avoid injury so we ask.

Comment: There seems to be many things you are uncertain but there is not a single question.

Answer (score 1):

Like most car radios, the Pioneer MVH-S320BT produces 270 fake (distorted peak) Watts plus lots of heating power when the alternator is charging the battery at 14.4V.

With a 12V battery the output will be 15W for each of the 4 channels that have 4 ohms speakers plus 21W for a 2 ohms sub-woofer (all at low distortion and no clipping) for total output power of 81W plus about 40W of heat.
The manual says the battery current is 10A at 14.4V which is about 121W at 12V.

Few people play a sound system that is turned up too loud and producing horrible-sounding clipping distortion. Music and speech have an average power that is much less than the momentary peaks.

5 speakers systems with proper enclosures will not be portable.
You counted only 3 speakers then the rear speakers are missing.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. So with 12 volts 10 amps I should be able to power everything without audio problems ? With this battery would the car radio work at its maximum performance? What I mean is that I have no idea how the consumption of an audio device like this works (For instance when you say "270 distorted peak fake watts" I don't know what you mean) so I would like to know what kind of battery (and why, since I want to learn new stuff that in my university cours they doesn't teach) to create in order to achieve my purpose.

Comment: Peak Watts are fake because they are simply double real watts, and distorted Watts are much more than undistorted Watts. The undistorted real output power from an amplifier depends on the supply voltage and the speaker impedance. A charging old lead acid battery is 14.5V but a fully charged 3-cells lithium battery is only 12.6V. A lead-acid car battery never drops below about 12.5V but the Lithium battery will drop to 9V and produce much less power. With a 12V lithium battery the amplifiers produce 21W into 2 ohms, 15W into 4 ohms and about 8W into 8 ohms.

Comment: Ok thank you very much, you've made your point very clear about battery. Now I have another doubt, the specs about the radio max output says: "50W x 4-ch 4ohm / 50W x 2-ch 4 ohm + 70W x 1-ch 2 ohm (subwoofer)" but I have 2 tweeters and 2 woofer with 4 ohm impedance and one 100W 4 ohm subwoofer, can I connect all of them ? If not what I need to do to use it all ? Maybe connect the subwoofer via RCA cable to a dedicated amplifier ? There are some formulas you used to obtain the Watt value you've written in your comment (also some resources where I can learn more about) ? Thanks again

Comment: The specs for the car radio say, "22W continuously into 4 ohms x 4." But that is with a 14.4V supply with the car engine charging the old lead-acid battery and it is with horrible distortion that is adding to the real output power. The specs also lie about it producing 50W x4 into 4 ohms, which must be fake doubled Watts numbers. The car radio has 4 channels for surround-sound but you have only enough woofers and tweeters for 2 channels. The car radio specs also lies about 70W into 2 ohms then into your 4 ohms sub-woofer the real power will be much less.

Comment: Companies who make cheap amplifiers lie about the output power. The car battery is charging at 14.4V which powers the amplifier. Each amplifier drives both speaker wires which effectively doubles the amplifier supply voltage which also double the speaker current. Then the amplifier gets a 28.8V supply and each output has a loss of about 5V peak-to peak which is a total output voltage swing of 28.8V - 5V= 23.8V. REAL speaker power = continuous RMS voltage x RMS current. They say fake PEAK power to double the power number.

Comment: The 24.8V p-p is divided by "the root of 2" which is 2.828 to calculate the REAL output RMS voltage swing of 23.8V/2.828=8.4V RMS. Then the REAL power into a 4 ohms speaker is (8.4V squared) / 4 ohms= 17.6W per channel at fairly low distortion.

Comment: Great explanation thanks. I have some questions. 17.6 W for both subwoofer and woofers (and tweeters)? This is the continuous power or the maximum ? (If there is any difference between them)The specs also says "14W RMS X 4-ch at 4ohm" what does it means ? Is different from the value of 17.6W you calculated?
Specs also says "RCA preout voltage 2V" having this data changes the calculations you made in some way? Are there other parameters that differentiate this car radio from another in terms of output power ? Thanks again

Comment: "Maximum" power is fake and is simply double the real continuous power. With a 14.4V supply, my calculated  power into 4 ohms is 17.6W at fairly low distortion. I guessed too low at the voltage loss. The specs for CTA-2006 say 14W into 4 ohms over the entire bandwidth at 1% distortion or less. Since our sensitivity of hearing is logarithmic then 14W sounds almost the same loudness as 17.6W.

Comment: The sub-woofer amplifier is rated for higher power into 2 ohms and produces almost the same power as the other amplifiers into 4 ohms. Woofer power and tweeter powers share the total power. 14W into the woofer or the tweeter by itself or 7W for each of them when both are playing. The preout has nothing to do with amplifier outputs.

Comment: Very clear, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Buy a ready-made 12 V power bank
2. Done